# Delta lake and ADLS Gen2 transactions

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

We are running a Delta lake on ADLS Gen2 with plenty of tables and Spark jobs. The Spark jobs are running in Databricks and we mounted the ADLS containers into DBFS (`abfss://delta@<our-adls-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/silver`). There's one container for each "tier", so `bronze`, `silver`, `gold`.

This setup has been stable for some months now, but last week, we've seen a sudden increase in transactions within our storage account, particularly in the `ListFilesystemDir` operations:

[image]

We've added some smaller jobs that read and write some data in that time frame, but turning them off did not reduce the amount of transactions back to the old level.

Two questions regarding this:

1. Is there some sort of documentation that explains which operation on a Delta table causes which kind of ADLS transactions?
2. Is it possible to find out which container/directory/Spark job/... causes this amount of transactions, without turning off the Spark jobs one by one?

Comment: are you using Structured Streaming for your jobs?

Comment: yes, structured streaming mostly, but there are also some batch jobs

Comment: what triggers are you using on the streaming jobs?

Comment: you mean ".trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 minute"))" for example? none, mostly, but that's because the batch duration is generally quite large (>5 minutes per batch)

Comment: I thought about this item: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/8.0#new-structured-streaming-default-trigger-interval-reduces-costs

Comment: "reduce costs for cloud storage such as listing" - nice, that's a very good point! will review all the jobs and apply triggers, thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexOtt thanks! The result is amazing! List operations are down to 1/3.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped.  It's not necessary that you upgrade to the latest version, you can set trigger in any of versions. In the latest version it's just set as default

Answer (score 1):

If you go into logs from your data lake (if you have log analytics enabled) you can view the exact timestamp, caller and target of the spike. Take that data and go into your databricks cluster and navigate to Spark UI. In there you should be able to see timestamps and jobs. There you can find what notebook is causing it.

Comment: ah nice, I didn't know that log analytics tracks all this, will give it a shot